# angular 4- how to call a method when a div is focused

Tags: angular

I'm building an app in angular 4. I need to call a function when a div is focused.
here is my html code,

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index" (focus)="loadPosts(i)">
      <mat-card class="post" >
      <mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-avatar src="assets/images/shiba1.jpg" class="example-header-image">
        <!-- <mat-card-title>sample Inu</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle> -->
      </mat-card-header>
      <!-- <img mat-card-image src="assets/images/shiba2.jpg"> -->
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
          {{ post.post }}
        </p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
    </div>
```

and my ts file.

```
loadPosts(val){
console.log(val);
}
```

I'm not getting that index values in console. I searched a lot to do this focus event, still now i didn't find a solution..
can anyone give a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'focus event' is not possible in a div. However,this may help you to some extent as:-

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index" (mouseover)="loadPosts(i)">
{{post}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no focus event in a div. So you can't do this.

Comment: then suggest to call a function when i focused that div

Comment: And what do you mean by 'focus'? You will have to rely on the events that a div 'listens'. Those are: mousedown, mouseup, mouseover, mousemove, mouseout, click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup. You will ahve to choose which is the best for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @christian for your valuable support